# YARN: '[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: npm, cmd, yarnpkg

I just cloned a github repo for local development and I'm now trying to run it on localhost, I ran yarn and got this error

```
'[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

In my packages.json file I have the following line that this error has come from

```
    "preinstall": "[ ! -f src/locales/translations/.git ] && git submodule deinit --all -f; git submodule update --init --recursive --remote",
```

How do I fix this issue? Thanks.

Here's the full message encase it's relevant:

```
yarn install v1.22.10
warning ..\..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ [ ! -f src/locales/translations/.git ] && git submodule deinit --all -f; git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
'[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: It looks like you're running a script intended for a Unix/Linux shell on a Windows Command Prompt. `[`, also known as `test`, is a standard command on all Unix-like shells; and the mention of "batch file" is a strong indicator of a DOS-like environment.

Comment: You could use something like Cygwin or WSL on Windows in order to be able to run shell commands.